# jquery mobile nested collapsible

Tags: jquery, mobile

I am adding dynamic content to a collapsible div.  When it is added, the div is collapsed but the added content is outside the div.  Using javascript console in chrome, I see the div is closed before the new content is added.  Code is below:'

```
<div data-role="collapsible" id="sendmessTMlist" data-collapsed="true">
        <h3>Select A Message</h3>
                <div data-role="collapsible" id="mymessages">
                <h3>My Messages</h3>
                <div data-role="content">My Message1<BR>
                <input data-inline="true" data-role="button" id="messageid" type="button" value="Insert" class="buttlink" />
                </div>
                </cfoutput>
           </div>
```

Here is the jquery code I use to add the content:

```
$("#mymessages").append('<div data-role="content">'+data.message+'<BR><input data-inline="true" data-role="button" id="'+data.message+'" type="button" value="Insert" class="buttlink" /></div>').trigger("create");
```

`$("Selector").find('div[data-role=collapsible]').collapsible();`

I have tried many different combinations of code, the above is what's left of the last pass.

What is missing in my javascript to put that inside the collapsible?

Comment: This sort of seems like a CSS issue to me.

Answer (score 3):

In short the problem is that you append your content outside the correct container.

The fact of the matter is that jQM in process of enhancing the markup inserts a `div` with a class `ui-collapsible-content` where the content is placed.

Given that you have this initial markup

```
<div data-role="collapsible" id="mymessages" data-collapsed="false" data-theme="c" data-content-theme="c">
    <h3>My Messages</h3>
</div>
```

After jQM enhanced it it looks that way.

```
<div data-role="collapsible" id="mymessages" data-collapsed="false" data-theme="c" data-content-theme="c" class="ui-collapsible ui-collapsible-inset">
    <h3 class="ui-collapsible-heading">
    <a href="#" class="ui-collapsible-heading-toggle ui-btn ui-btn-up-c ui-fullsize ui-btn-icon-left ui-corner-top" data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-icon="plus" data-iconpos="left" data-theme="c" data-mini="false"><span class="ui-btn-inner ui-corner-top"><span class="ui-btn-text">My Messages<span class="ui-collapsible-heading-status"> click to collapse contents</span></span><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-shadow ui-icon-minus">&nbsp;</span></span></a>
    </h3>
    <div class="ui-collapsible-content ui-body-c ui-corner-bottom" aria-hidden="false">
    </div>
</div>
```

See that newly added `div`?

That being said you need to add and refresh your content like this:

```
$("#mymessages div.ui-collapsible-content").append(html);
$("#mymessages").trigger("create");
```

Here is working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pmatseykanets/a5Fyk/) for you.

*And yes, you have a typo in provided markup. You should have* `</div>` *instead of *`</cfoutput>`.

Comment: @user1968854 Did it help? Do you need more help with your question?

Answer (score 0):

It could be the `<BR>` tag after the message that is being added dynamically that is causing it. Also the closing tag `</cfoutput>` looks a little out of place.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of appending it, you need to insert it in the last div child element (The one that is being dynamically added by JQM) like this:

```
var data = '<div data-role="content">'+data.message+'<BR><input data-inline="true" data-role="button" id="'+data.message+'" type="button" value="Insert" class="buttlink" /></div>';
$('#sendmessTMlist div:last-child').html(data).trigger("create");
```